# How to do my XML Document to looks like the example in C# .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, compare

How to make my XML Document to looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Diff>
<Delete file="file0.ext"/>
<Create file="file1.ext"/>
<Create dir="dir1"/>
<Create dir="dir1\dir2"/>
<Create file="dir1\dir2\file2.ext"/>
</Diff>
```

If i start from this :

```
static class DirectoryComparer
{
public static XmlDocument Compare(string oldPath, string newPath)
{
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
// TODO: Needs to fill "xml" here
return xml;
}
```

}

Comment: usually you don't just *write an xml-file*, but instead create some data and write that to xml. I'd suggest to create a class-structure and use XmlSerializer to write that to whatever.

Comment: You can add children and elements to your XML based on the root. Try to take a look at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XmlDocument instance has a [`CreateElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createelement?view=netframework-2.0) method  that allows you to create elements for your XmlDocument instance. The newly created Element (that is an XmlNode) can then be added to the Document Object Model by calling [`AppendChild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild?view=netframework-2.0). The Element has a [`SetAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement.setattribute?view=netframework-2.0) methode to add attributes to the element.

Combining all that an implementation to get exactly your example XML might loo like this:

```
static class DirectoryComparer
{
    public static XmlDocument Compare(string oldPath, string newPath)
    {
        XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.AppendChild(xml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));
        
        XmlElement diff = xml.CreateElement("Diff");
        xml.AppendChild(diff);
        
        diff.AppendChild(DeleteFile(xml,"file0.ext"));
        diff.AppendChild(CreateFile(xml,"file1.ext"));
        diff.AppendChild(CreateDir(xml,"dir1"));
        diff.AppendChild(CreateDir(xml,@"dir1\dir2"));
        diff.AppendChild(CreateFile(xml,@"dir1\dir2\file2.ext"));
        return xml;
    }
    
    private static XmlElement DeleteFile(XmlDocument xml, string file) 
    {
        XmlElement delete = xml.CreateElement("Delete");
        delete.SetAttribute("file", file);
        return delete;
    }
    
    private static XmlElement CreateFile(XmlDocument xml, string file) 
    {
        return CreateFileOrDir(xml, "file", file);
    }
    
    private static XmlElement CreateDir(XmlDocument xml, string dir) 
    {
        return CreateFileOrDir(xml, "dir", dir);
    }
    
    private static XmlElement CreateFileOrDir(XmlDocument xml, string attribute,string value) 
    {
        XmlElement create = xml.CreateElement("Create");
        create.SetAttribute(attribute, value);
        return create;
    }
}
```

And when run from LinqPad the output looks like this:

[image: xml output from LinqPad]

Answer (score 0):

Using Xml Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication40
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ident = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?><Diff></Diff>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ident);
            XElement root = doc.Root;

            root.Add(new object[] {
                new XElement("Delete", new XAttribute("file", "file0.ext")),
                new XElement("Create", new XAttribute("file", "file1.ext")),
                new XElement("Create", new XAttribute("dir", "dir1")),
                new XElement("Create", new XAttribute("dir", "dir2")),
                new XElement("Create", new XAttribute("file", @"dir1\dir2\file2.ext"))
            });

            doc.Save(FILENAME);      
        }
    }      
}
```